# Cannot setup Celery as daemon on server

Tags: python, django, celery, daemon

I cannot setup Celery as daemon on server (django 1.6.11, celery 3.1, Ubuntu 14.04)
Tried lot of options, can anyone place full setting of working configuration to run celery as daemon?

I am very disappointed from official docs http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html#generic-init-scripts - none of this working, no full step-by-step tutorial. Zero (!!!) videos on youtube on how to setup daemon.

Now i able to run celery simple by celery worker -A engine -l info -E
tasks from django are executed successfully.

I have done configs:

/etc/defaults/celery

```
    # Name of nodes to start
# here we have a single node
CELERYD_NODES="w1"
# or we could have three nodes:
#CELERYD_NODES="w1 w2 w3"

# Absolute path to "manage.py"
CELERY_BIN="/var/www/engine/manage.py"

# How to call manage.py
CELERYD_MULTI="celery multi"

# Extra command-line arguments to the worker
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=2"

# %N will be replaced with the first part of the nodename.
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%N.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%N.pid"

# Workers should run as an unprivileged user.
CELERYD_USER="root"
CELERYD_GROUP="root"
```

/etc/init.d/celeryd
got from https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/3.1/extra/generic-init.d/celeryd  without changes

Now, when i go to console and run:
cd /etc/init.d
celery multi start w1

i see output:

```
celery multi v3.1.11 (Cipater)
> Starting nodes...
        > w1@engine: OK
```

So, no errors! Tasks are not invoked and i cannot figure out whats wrong.

Comment: Link to the updated [Daemonizing page](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/v5.2.3/userguide/daemonizing.html) on docs.celeryq.dev.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to use [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/). It's better way than init scripts, because you can run multiple Celery instances for different projects on one server. Example config for Supervisor you can find in [Celery repo](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/3.1/extra/supervisord/celeryd.conf) or fully working example from my project:

```
# /etc/supervisor/conf.d/celery.conf
[program:celery]
command=/home/newspos/.virtualenvs/newspos/bin/celery worker -A newspos --loglevel=INFO
user=newspos
environment=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="newspos.settings"
directory=/home/newspos/projects/newspos/
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopwaitsecs = 600
killasgroup=true
startsecs=10
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery/newspos-celeryd.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery/newspos-celeryd.log
```

Comment: Unfortunately: Supervisor requires Python 2.4 or later but does not work on any version of Python 3.  You are using version 3.4.3   - when do pip install

Comment: @Vic Install supervisord system wide with package manager. You can do it in Ubuntu with `sudo apt-get install supervisor`. This way supervisor will use system's Python 2.7.

Comment: Thanx, this works, but what's next? I put file celery.conf to /etc/supervisor/conf.d, changed command=/var/www/engine/celery worker -A engine --loglevel=INFO  then  user=root    and environment=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="engine.settings" and   directory=/var/www/engine/ and now how do start daemon? should i remove /etc/init.d/celeryd scripts?

Comment: @Vic Yes, you can remove init scripts you've created. Now reload supervisor so it'll read and apply your new config: `sudo supervisorctl reload`. In future you can restart celery instance with `sudo supervisorctl restart celery`, but if you change celery.conf reload supervisor again.

Comment: As expected not working), when do: sudo supervisorctl reload  shows: Restarted supervisord. Then i test task - not invoked. When do 'sudo supervisorctl restart celery' shows  '
celery: ERROR (not running)
celery: ERROR (no such file)
' I am not sure: is it really will work under python 2.7 and deal with django and other modules, all installed to python 3.4 ?

Comment: Yes, it will work. Please post logs from /var/log/supervisor/ and check your command. I think it isn't correct. Replace `/var/www/engine/celery` with result of `which celery` (that will print real absolute path to celery).

Comment: Worked! Path was /usr/local/bin/celery  (strange, because path to celery.py another). Now task is working! In engine-celeryd.log now i see all standard output by celery ! You are cool, i accept answer!

Comment: Here's a supervisor example for celery 5.x: [celeryd.conf](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/v5.2.3/extra/supervisord/celeryd.conf), [change history](https://github.com/celery/celery/commits/v5.2.3/extra/supervisord/celeryd.conf).